# How to apply pull to refresh without showing the scroll in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I applied the "pull to refresh" in the react-native app using the scrollView and ListView but I want to use "pull to refresh" for a View without scrolling.

Comment: You can set `scroll={false}` on a ScrollView.  You could also wrap a regular View inside a PanResponder and build the pulling functionality using that.

Comment: @Abe could you please share an example, how to apply pull to refresh using "PanResponder"

Comment: The docs are good, have you checked them out?  [Link here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder).  Basically wrap a view with one, measure the distance of the Y change in the gesture, and animate/use a callback when you hit your desired distance.